# How to utilize a value from the response of one .AJAX function in another as a parameter to insert into the POST request

Tags: html, ajax, http-post

I'm trying to use a value received from the response in one ajax function as a parameter in another ajax function call in an html file. 
 I'm sorry if this is very basic, but I'm very new at this.

I've tried to call the value the same as I do in the body of the HTML and many other attempts.

1 - Here is the initial call (working):

```
$.ajax({
          "url":api_base+"/endpoint_01",
          "type":"GET",
          "contentType":"application/json",
          "success":function(data){
            var data = data[0];
            $('#dash_value').html(data.value);
          }
        });
```

2 - Here is how I access this in html (:

```
<div class="highlighted-text" id="dash_value"></div>
```

3 - I don't know how to utilize this later in the file:

```
function function_02(){
          $.ajax({
            "url":api_base+"endpoint_02?value=" + dash_value,
            "type":"POST",
            "beforeSend":function(){
              $('#button_01').prop('disabled', true);
            },
            "dataType":"text",
            "success":function(data){
              swal(data, {
                icon : "success",
                buttons: false,
                timer: 3000
              });
            },
            "complete":function(){
              $('#button_01').prop('disabled', false);
            }
          });
        }
```

the POST should be sent like this:

```
   https://endpoint02?value=dash_value
```

but I'm getting everything except that.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring a variable outside the scope of the Ajax method so code outside the method can access it later then assign the variable to the returned data inside the ajax scope:

```
var outerScopeData = "";

$.ajax({
  "url":api_base+"/endpoint_01",
  "type":"GET",
  "contentType":"application/json",
  "success":function(data){
    var data = data[0];

    // add this here:
    outerScopeData = data.value;

    $('#dash_value').html(data.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `dash_value` before you make the second ajax call.

```
function function_02(){
         const dash_value = $("dash_value").data()
          $.ajax({
            "url":api_base+"endpoint_02?value=" + dash_value,
            "type":"POST",
            "beforeSend":function(){
              $('#button_01').prop('disabled', true);
            },
            "dataType":"text",
            "success":function(data){
              swal(data, {
                icon : "success",
                buttons: false,
                timer: 3000
              });
            },
            "complete":function(){
              $('#button_01').prop('disabled', false);
            }
          });
        }
```